# Quicklaunch like functionality in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, quicklaunch

Windows 7 changes the taskbar and removes quicklaunch which I used heavily and miss somewhat.

I know you can re-add quicklaunch to the taskbar but it seems to me a better idea would be an application that sat in the taskbar and displayed the quicklaunch icons when the cursor hovered over it, similar to the other menus that are displayed when an taskbar item is right-clicked in Windows 7. That would give you the speed and convenience of the old quicklaunch but not use up any screen real estate.

Does anyone know of any settings or applications for Windows 7 like this?

Comment: What's wrong with the Windows 7 taskbar? I don't understand what a Quick Launch menu can give you that the superbar can't.

Comment: I agree with musicfreak.  Pin the ones you like, then drag them around to reorder them.  That's very quicklaunch-like, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have look at **7stacks**, I think it's more or less what you want to do.

[image]

The homepage is [here](http://www.alastria.com/index.php?p=software-7s) and there is a review [here](http://www.intowindows.com/7stacks-stacks-for-windows-7-taskbar/).

PS:  apparently their website is broken, as you cannot go into other pages nor even download. Use [this link](http://www.alastria.com/files/7stacksSetup.exe) to download it.

Comment: It doesn't pop open on hover but apart from that, exactly what I was thinking of. I pointed it an the Windows quick launch folder and I was up and running. Thanks.

Comment: This app is slow to load - specially when you click to expand.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the entire purpose of the new taskbar to depricate quick launch and application and notification windows and replace them with a single smooth interface? What does quick launch do that pinning an application to the new taskbar won't do?

Comment: In Vista I expanded the taskbar to be two rows, one for quicklaunch (with 25 odd apps) and the other for running programs. I would find it useful because 20 pinned apps wouldn't leave much room for anything else in Windows 7.

Comment: Unless you have 10 **other** things running besides instances of your 25 quicklaunch apps, you won't need more than a single bar.

Comment: I often have lots of programs open, sometimes on a laptop with a smaller screen.

Comment: Try stretching  the taskbar to 2 rows and enabling small icons. I have 16 icons on my taskbar and it's not spilling over to the second row yet.

Comment: I have putty on the quick-launch bar. Makes it easy to start 2 or 3 sessions instantaneously. The new task-bar assumes a single session and makes you work hard for the others...